# how to set method and call it for many slideshow animation

Tags: android, methods, slideshow

One of my app activity was slideshow with many animation depend on user choice and if user uncheck all it will open pager activity , the below code work perfectly but i have to repeat the code with (if and if else) method many time for each animation which is redundant , is there is a way to set one method and call it for every animation and if unchecked all will open pager activity ,

any help will be appreciated .

**SlideShow.java**

```
public class SlideShow extends Activity {

public int currentimageindex=0;
Timer timer;
TimerTask task;
ImageView slidingimage;

private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {
        R.drawable.day_one_1, R.drawable.day_one_2, R.drawable.day_one_3,
        R.drawable.day_one_4, R.drawable.day_one_5, R.drawable.day_one_6,
        R.drawable.day_one_7, R.drawable.day_one_8, R.drawable.day_one_9, 
        };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            AnimateandSlideShow();              
        }
    };

    int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

    int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

         mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    }

    }, delay, period);             

}      

private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    boolean animation = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation", true);             
    boolean animation_one = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_one", false);
    boolean animation_two = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_two", false);    
    boolean animation_three = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_three", false);
    boolean animation_four = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_four", false);
    boolean animation_five = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_five", false);              


 if (animation == true) {   
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);               
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if(animation_one == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;        
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);        
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if (animation_two == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);       
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  

}else if (animation_three == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);       
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  

}else if(animation_four == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;        
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in_2);        
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if (animation_five == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flip);       
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  


}else if(animation == false && animation_one == false && animation_two == false){
    Intent intent = new Intent(SlideShow.this, ImagePager.class);                                     
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent p = new Intent("com.test.test.SETTING");
        startActivity(p);
    break;
    }

return false; 
}
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

i would try something like this...

```
{
    ...
    boolean noPager = true;
    noPager = doAnim(R.anim.custom_anim, animation, noPager);
    noPager = doAnim(R.anim.fade_in, animation_one, noPager);
    noPager = doAnim(R.anim.fade_out, animation_two, noPager);
    noPager = doAnim(R.anim.bounce, animation_three, noPager);
    noPager = doAnim(R.anim.fade_in_2, animation_four, noPager);
    noPager = doAnim(R.anim.flip, animation_five, noPager);
    if(!noPager){
        Intent intent = new Intent(SlideShow.this, ImagePager.class);                                     
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private boolean doAnim(int anim, boolean yes_no, boolean notDone){
    if(!yes_no || !notDone){
        return true;
    }
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, anim);       
    slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the imagepager only run when unchecked all checkboxs and start new class showing imagespager but all animation applied to images in the slideshow activity ,what i want to apply all animations and pager class to same images in one class and one method , thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't really understand your question. My code does the same as yours, only redundant. and that was your question, wasn't it?

Comment: i try it , its open with image pager then when you check any animation and back to images it doesnt apply animation and stack on one image also i cant scroll it

Comment: Sorry i Just saw something really dumb in my code, try another time with the edited version.